# sIFR: dynamically inserting umlaut causes trouble

Tags: javascript, sifr, diacritics

let me state cleary at the beginning that I know about the embedding issue in flash. 
So, to the point. If sIFR replaces an umlaut (ä,ö,ü) which is hard coded in the HTML file everythings works fine.
But when I want to insert it dynamically it is not displayed.
I played around with charset options to specifiy the javascript file i'm referencing but it doesnt change a thing.

Here's JavaScript and sIFR code:

```
sIFR.replacements["#image-counter span"][0].replaceText("ö");
```

I tried as well to replace `"ö"` by `"&ouml;"` and `"&#246"` but this doesnt work around it either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

ok the issue seems solve to me by now. i tried another charset (I used utf-8 in the first place)

but when I reference my js file with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/...js" charset="ISO-8859-1"></script>
```

it seems to work